# unable to get html5 geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, api, geolocation

I am learning about html5 geolocation api, I have written this simple bit of code for practice. However I keep getting "location information unavailable", and I have no idea why. I am pretty new to this, and would appreciate some help.

Here is my code.
`var userLocation = document.querySelector(".location");`

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    userLocation.textContent = "Checking Location...";
  }
  else {
    userLocation.textContent = "Unable to retrieve location..";
  }
});

function showPosition(position){
  userLocation.textContent = position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error){
   switch(error.code){
     case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are loading the page over httpS also make sure that you have never denied permission to location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it turns out it was an issue with my PCI card not being able to work with linux ubuntu. Thanks for the help though.